# Alert for varying DropDowns?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the code below to trigger an alert if the user fails to make a choice from a specific dropdown menu.

```
  <script>
          function selection(){    
            var sel = document.getElementById('product_configure_variants');    
            var selectedText = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
            if (selectedText.startsWith("Make a choice...")) {
               alert('PLEASE MAKE ALL ORDER FORM SELECTIONS');
               return false;
            }
            return true;
         }
    </script>
```

The  code above works just fine. But now I want to do the same for other dropdown menus, but this presents me  with a problem. The ID of these dropdowns vary. The ID looks like this: `id="product_configure_custom_2197256"`
the number of the ID varies per drop down. They are generated by a webshop backoffice.

**How can I use the code above with these varying dropdown ID's?**

Answer (score 1):

you could pass the `id` with in function  .Apply the function in html like   `selection(this.id)` if the same element id else some other element id try `selection(thatelementid)`

```
function selection(id){    
            var sel = document.getElementById(id);    
            var selectedText = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
            if (selectedText.startsWith("Make a choice...")) {
               alert('PLEASE MAKE ALL ORDER FORM SELECTIONS');
               return false;
            }
            return true;
         }
```

**Example code**

```js
function selection(id){    
      console.log(id)
                var sel = document.getElementById(id);    
                var selectedText = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
                //f (selectedText.startsWith("Make a choice...")) {
                   alert('PLEASE MAKE ALL ORDER FORM SELECTIONS');
                   return false;
                //}
                return true
                
                }
```

```html
<select id="check1" onchange="selection(this.id)">
<option>one</option>
<option>two</option>
<option>three</option>
</select>
<select id="check2" onchange="selection(this.id)">
<option>one</option>
<option>two</option>
<option>three</option>
</select>
<select id="check3" onchange="selection(this.id)">
<option>one</option>
<option>two</option>
<option>three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, @prasad. But this does not show an alert. It is not working.

Comment: code behaves as right.kindly show your markup(html) .its help full find out your need

Comment: @Eddy see my updated answer.I was added some working snippet kindly workout like that